# How to access ActiveRecords associated Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables, qip_changes and mac_addresses, which have a belongs_to relation. When i try to access the mac_address table from a QipChange class object, i run into "undefined method `MyDbColumName=' for nil:NilClass"

i can fetch my data, but iam not able to write into the associated table:

```
2.4.1 :044 > i = QipChange.first
QipChange Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "qip_changes".* FROM "qip_changes" ORDER BY 
"qip_changes"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<QipChange id: 2, created_at: "2018-08-21 08:31:48", updated_at: 
"2018-08-21 08:31:48", tenant: "BMC-Test", object_type: "Subnet", action: 
"add", object_data: "blabalalaalla", implementation_status: "started", 
server_response: "", user_id: 1, user_cache: "test"> 
2.4.1 :045 > i.mac_address
MacAddress Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "mac_addresses".* FROM "mac_addresses" 
WHERE "mac_addresses"."qip_change_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["qip_change_id", 2], 
["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil 
2.4.1 :046 > i.mac_address.mac_address = "asocnasc"
NoMethodError: undefined method `mac_address=' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):46
```

I guess iam just using the wrong syntax to access the associated table, but i cannot find something on the web how to do so.

my Models:

```
class QipChange < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_one :mac_address
end

class MacAddress < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :qip_change
end
```

from psql:

```
ipmatedevel=# \d mac_addresses
                                       Table "public.mac_addresses"
    Column     |            Type             |                         Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id            | bigint                      | not null default nextval('mac_addresses_id_seq'::regclass)
 mac_address   | character varying           |
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 qip_change_id | bigint                      |
Indexes:
    "mac_addresses_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_mac_addresses_on_qip_change_id" btree (qip_change_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_8002186396" FOREIGN KEY (qip_change_id) REFERENCES qip_changes(id)

qipmatedevel=# \d qip_changes
                                           Table "public.qip_changes"
        Column         |            Type             |                        Modifiers                         
-----------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id                    | bigint                      | not null default nextval('qip_changes_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at            | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at            | timestamp without time zone | not null
 tenant                | character varying           | 
 object_type           | character varying           | 
 action                | character varying           | 
 object_data           | character varying           | 
 implementation_status | character varying           | 
 server_response       | character varying           | 
 user_id               | bigint                      | 
 user_cache            | character varying           | not null
Indexes:
    "qip_changes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_qip_changes_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_3207a22986" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "mac_addresses" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_8002186396" FOREIGN KEY (qip_change_id) REFERENCES qip_changes(id)
```

edit: so iam curios if my association is working. Since a query is produced once i enter "i.mac_address" it seems that this is working, am i right ?

edit:

```
i.create_mac_address(mac_address: "aconasic")
```

that worked to create the mac_address. What do i need to do to access it starting from i ?

works with the following once the mac_address has been created:

```
i.mac_address.mac_address
```

Comment: It seems that this `QipChange` has no associated mac address. Are you sure it's there?

Comment: Can you post the schema???

Comment: added my models and the db output

Comment: Models seem to be OK. How do you create a mac address for a qip change?

Comment: @Bastian You got nil as output for the query i.mac_address, as it says you donot have any mac_address created for the associated qip_changes record

Comment: for every QipChange i want to create the corresponding MacAddress. So basically i fetch a change, then assigne a value to the mac_address.

Comment: Please, show us the code for storing mac address

Comment: @Bastian updated my answer for creating a mac_address for qipchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update an attribute in rails you need to do

```
 TABLE_NAME.update(ATTRIBUTENAME: "")
```

For example If you want to update the mac_address the you need to do

```
i.mac_address.update(mac_address: "asocnasc")
```

And with the query you have posted it donot seem like there is a association between those two tables

If you want to create a new mac_address for a qipChange them you need to do

```
i.create_mac_address(mac_address: MAC_ADDRESSS) here i is your QIPCHANGE
```

Comment: a query is send to the database when i enter  i.mac_address so i would exect that it is working ?

Comment: Yeah Its working but you cannot update/create a record in the way that you specified

Comment: create_mac_address worked ! just one more question: how do i access the column mac_address when i want my QipChange object to be the base for the query. Again i would expect something like ´i.mac_address.mac_address´

Comment: if you have a mac_address created for the QipChange then i.mac_address.mac_address works but if you donot have  the macc_address created then it throws the error

Comment: oh gosh, i have just seen that it didnt work due to a type. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Thanks,  Happy to help!